# Converting last 10 images into a gif file

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I need to generate using imagemagick a gif file from a list of images with the following structure:

```
image [00-15].jpg
image [00-45].jpg
image [01-15].jpg
image [01-45].jpg
image [02-15].jpg
image [02-45].jpg
image [03-15].jpg
image [03-45].jpg
```

But i need to do it using only the 10 most recent images. How do I solve it using bash script?

Comment: Small clarification question - sorry if this sounds stupid: do the filenames look *exactly* like `image [00-15].jpg`, or are you using `[...]` to indicate some sort of range? Adding a small list of actual images could be interesting and useful.

Comment: Yes the filenames look exactly like image [00-15].jpg. Approximately every 30 minutes a new file is added. That's why I need to create the animation with the last 10 images.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use ffmpeg.

```
        For creating a video from many images:

               ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -s WxH foo.avi

       The syntax "foo-%03d.jpeg" specifies to use a decimal number composed of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It is the same syntax supported
       by the C printf function, but only formats accepting a normal integer are suitable.

       When importing an image sequence, -i also supports expanding shell-like wildcard patterns (globbing) internally, by selecting the image2-specific "-pattern_type glob"
       option.

       For example, for creating a video from filenames matching the glob pattern "foo-*.jpeg":

               ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 12 -i 'foo-*.jpeg' -s WxH foo.avi
```

I use this tool for combining video fragments to full episodes.

Locally I was able to get a gif by running `ffmpeg -i %02d.png output.gif` where I had 01.png, 02.png, 03.png, and 04.png. You'll have to play around with the options for timing and stuff, but it's totally do-able.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand your use of []. Are the brackets real in your filenames? If not, then

```
convert -delay 50 image*.jpg[-1--10] -loop 0 animation.gif
```

Unfortunately, it will load all your images and use only the last 10. But it will use a lot of memory to load all the jpgs.

Comment: Yes the brackets are real in my filenames. Approximately every 30 minutes a new file is added. That's why I need to create the animation with the last 10 images.